# Creating a speech service from Azure Speech to Text Rest API

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I can see there are two versions of REST API endpoints for Speech to Text in the Microsoft documentation links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text

One endpoint is [https://.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken] referring to version 1.0 and another one is [api/speechtotext/v2.0/transcriptions] referring to version 2.0. How can I create a speech-to-text service in Azure Portal for the latter one?

Whenever I create a service in different regions, it always creates for speech to text v1.0.

Any tips?

PS: I've Visual Studio Enterprise account with monthly allowance and I am creating a subscription (s0) (paid) service rather than free (trial) (f0) service.

Thanks, 
Ozgur

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

All official Microsoft `Speech` resource created in Azure Portal is valid for Microsoft Speech 2.0

I understand that this `v1.0` in the token url is surprising, but this token API is not part of Speech API.

So go to Azure Portal, create a Speech resource, and you're done.

[image]

If you want to be sure, go to your created resource, copy your key. That's what you will use for Authorization, in a header called `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header`, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#authentication)

Demo:

- Get your key on your created resource
- Go to https://[REGION].cris.ai/swagger/ui/index (REGION being the region where you created your speech resource)
- Click on Authorize: you will see both forms of Authorization

[image: authorization button]

[image: authorization process]

- Paste your key in the 1st one (subscription_Key), validate
- Close this window
- Test one of the endpoints, for example the one listing the speech endpoints, by going to the GET operation on `/api/speechtotext/v2.0/endpoints`
- Click 'Try it out' and you will get a 200 OK reply!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Understand your confusion because MS document for this is ambiguous. Per my research,let me clarify it as below: Two type services for Speech-To-Text exist, `v1` and `v2`.

v1 could be found under Cognitive Service structure when you create it:

[image]

Based on statements in the [Speech-to-text REST API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text):

Before using the speech-to-text REST API, understand:

- Requests that use the REST API and transmit audio directly can only
  contain up to 60 seconds of audio.
- The speech-to-text REST API only returns final results. Partial
  results are not provided.

If sending longer audio is a requirement for your application, consider using the Speech SDK or a file-based REST API, like batch
transcription.

So v1 has some limitation for file formats or audio size. If you have further more requirement,please navigate to v2 api- Batch Transcription hosted by Zoom Media.You could figure it out if you read this [document](https://www.zoommedia.ai/purchase-zoom-media-speech-to-text-through-azure-marketplace/) from ZM. You could create that Speech Api in Azure Marketplace:

[image]

That's the creation page for it :

[image]

Also,you could view the API document at the foot of above page, it's [V2 API document](https://apidocs.zoommedia.ai/).

Final tip:

v1's endpoint like: https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken

v2's endpoint like:

[image]

Comment: Helpful feedback: (1) the personal pronoun "I" is upper-case; (2) quote blocks (via the `>` device) are for quotes, and are not a general highlighter; (3) chatty material like "hope that helps" or "hope this is clear" is regarded as "fluff" and will be removed. It is kind to take mercy on editors and not add it in the first place.

Comment: Jay, Actually I was looking for Microsoft Speech API rather than Zoom Media API. Hence your answer didn't help.